# Converting int to float with known precision

Tags: python, type-conversion

I've exported my location data from Google but one thing they have in the resulting json is that both latitudes and longitudes are stored as integers. For example:

```
-37785037   # latitude
144939405  # longitude
```

Since I know where I roughly was at that time it's clear that the actual coords are -37.785.. and 144.939..., i.e. somewhere in northern suburbs of Melbourne, AU.

Also, by examining the data I established that in all cases the values have a 7-digit precision. So reading this json I'm converting coordinates to integers using this very ugly construct: first I convert int to string, then take integer part, add a dot, add floating part and then convert all to float:

```py
loc = {}

for i in data['locations']:
    try:
        t = dt.datetime.strptime(i['timestamp'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
    except ValueError:
        t = dt.datetime.strptime(i['timestamp'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
        
    lat = float(f"{str(i['latitudeE7'])[:-7]}.{str(i['latitudeE7'])[-7:]}")
    lon = float(f"{str(i['longitudeE7'])[:-7]}.{str(i['longitudeE7'])[-7:]}")
    loc[t] = {
        'latitude': lat,
        'longitude': lon
            }
```

This works, but looks hella ugly.

Is there a cleaner way of converting an int to float when you know the precision of the resulting float?

Comment: If you want precision use [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) instead of `float`. Parsing a string doesn't mean you'll avoid rounding errors. With `Decimal` you can read the values as Decimal and divide them by 1000000 without losing precision

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I don't really care about rounding errors because I don't believe that a consumer-grade GPS is capable of measuring coordinates to this level of precision anyway. I believe a GPS unit in a mobile should be able to achieve ~4-digit precision. All the rest are superfluous.

Comment: Actually it does. 4 decimals is 10 meters at the equator. Floating point errors add up too. There's a lot of trigonometry and multiplications involved in geographical calculations. If you use a spatial/GIS library you may be able to keep using ints instead of floats.

Comment: `4-digit precision` that's 11 meters. You'd end up in the wrong house or the wrong side of the street to begin with.  A smartphone is far better than that already. Try using a spatial library. Those problems are solved

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yes, 10-ish meters is something that I believe a phone GPS should be comfortable with. Maybe more accurate would be 4-5-digit precision. In industrial applications if you want to achieve 1-meter precision or higher you need a specialised GPS receiver. And I'm fine with wrong house or wrong side of street anyway, for this project at least.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, government site says that smartphone GPS is typically accurate within about 5m: https://www.gps.gov/systems/gps/performance/accuracy/#:~:text=For%20example%2C%20GPS%2Denabled%20smartphones,receivers%20and%2For%20augmentation%20systems.

Comment: Now imagine a self-driving car being 10 meters off. No, there's no reason to refuse using a purpose-made library. You're trying to solve an already solved problem. `government site says that smartphone GPS` phones don't use GPS only, for the last 15 years.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, actually driving applications "stick" to the known roads. So even if the GPS reading shows you're in the field the app will try to put you on the nearest known road within a certain tolerance. This is how you can still use your Google Maps while driving in a tunnel.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yes phones use a combination of a GPS/GLONASS/Galileo, WiFi and triangulation from cell towers. Out of these, satellites is the most accurate data source. I'm really not trying to solve already solved problem. It's just for this project I don't really care about rounding errors which will amount to millimeters/centemetres that a smartphone can't measure anyways. The last 2-3 digits are superflous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If precision is fixed, simply dividing your value by 1e6 will give you the correct answer:

`-37785037/1e6=-37.785037`

Comment: OMG! I think I should just kill myself this very moment lol.

Comment: No worries, we've all been there at some point in time. Take a break and grab a cup of coffee or tea :)

Comment: This will introduce rounding errors but then, so does `float()`. It may be enough if you don't really care about a few meters. Or ending up at the wrong site of the street

Comment: The size of the error depends on the location too. [This page](https://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Decimal_degrees) maps decimal places to distance at the equator, where the error will be largest